# Why does the length of $\vec{e_\theta}=\frac{d}{d\theta}(\vec{e_r})$ matter?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, vectors, circles, classical-mechanics

Define:

- $\vec{e_r}:=\vec{i}\cos\theta+\vec{j}\sin\theta$;
- $\vec{e_\theta}:=\frac{d}{d\theta}(\vec{e_r})=-\vec{i}\sin\theta+\vec{j}\cos\theta.$

Consider:

- a unit circle with centre $O$;
- a point $A_\theta$ with $\overrightarrow{OA_\theta}=\overrightarrow{e_r}$;
- a point $B_\theta$ with $\overrightarrow{A_\theta B_\theta}=\overrightarrow{e_\theta}$;
- a particle $P$ at $A_\theta$.

$P$ never reaches any given $B_\theta$ since $\overrightarrow{e_\theta}$ is continually deflected in a direction anti-parallel to $\overrightarrow{e_r}$. In fact, $P$ only ever travels a differential distance towards $B_\theta$. So what difference would it make if $\overrightarrow{e_\theta}$ had a different length?

Comment: That's not the motive, [this is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvilinear_coordinates#Covariant_and_contravariant_bases).

Comment: Tip on formatting vectors: you need only `\vec{\cdot}`, where $\cdot$ is replaced by whatever you need to be designated as a vector.  Click on the edit link, and see some of the changes I made.

Comment: @amWhy Thanks, that'll save me some typing.

Comment: Yes, indeed, @mjc.  Your approach worked fine, but we all appreciate time-savers when we find them.

Comment: @J.G. The idea of a curvilinear coordinate system is new to me and sounds like it might have some useful answers, but I don't really understand what the section you linked to is saying. Can you elaborate a little on why this answers my question?

Comment: What is the dynamic that you allude to when you say "$P$ never reaches any given $B_θ$"? $P$ is a point on the unit circle, while $B_θ$ is a point on a circle with radius $\sqrt2$ around the same origin. If $e_θ$ had a different length, then the second radius would be $\sqrt{1+\|e_θ\|^2}$ by Pythagoras.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I mean: given a change in $\theta$, I expect $\vec{e_\theta}$ to represent a corresponding change in position, given on the unit circle by $\vec{e_r}$. But the point $B_\theta$ picked out by $\vec{e_\theta}$ does not lie on the path of a particle sweeping out angle on the circle, and is never approached by more than a differential amount. This situation would remain true if we scaled the circle and the vectors by a common factor. So what does the length of the tangential vector represent in terms of change in position?

Comment: That is the angular velocity. Already Euler proved that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+i\frac{\Deltaθ}n\right)^n=\cos(\Deltaθ)+i\sin(\Deltaθ).$$ So yes, if you apply the Euler method to this dynamic, you get an outward spiral, but as you make the steps smaller, this spiral becomes ever tighter around the unit circle.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Wouldn't angular velocity be $\frac{d}{dt}(\theta(t))$ rather than $\frac{d\vec{r}}{d\theta}$? With regards to the spiral, isn't this what I'm saying? $P$ only travels a differential length in the direction of a tangent before changing direction slightly. If it travelled further, it would make an outward spiral. But if it only ever travels a differential length, what does the non-differential length of the tangential vector represent? Thanks for pointing out the Euler formula, that seems useful.

Comment: If you use  an i-large number $N$ of pieces of i-small distance $Δθ$ so that $NΔθ=θ$, then the radius during the Euler method increases as $$\left(1+\Deltaθ^2\right)^N=\exp(N(\Deltaθ^2-\tfrac12\Deltaθ^4\pm...))=\exp(θ\,Δθ-\tfrac12θ\,Δθ^3\pm...),$$ which is only an i-small distance away from $1$.

Comment: The way you use "tangent vector", you need to have in your original formulation $θ =t$ or directly $θ$ as independent variable.

Comment: @LutzLehmann The Euler stuff sounds good and will take me some time to chew over. More briefly (I hope), could you clarify why my use of "tangent vector" has the requirement you say?

Comment: Because you define $e_θ=\frac{de_r}{dθ}$, where you obviously use $θ$ as the independent variable of the dynamic.

Comment: @LutzLehmann OK, yes, that is what I meant. So if $\theta$ need not be a function of time, what made you say "That is the angular velocity"?

Comment: Back to my original question, what is the intended dynamic, where does time enter your question?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I intended to keep it out. Have I included it unintentionally?

Comment: You ascribe a motion to $P$ when you say that it "reaches" or not some location, that implies an advancement in time. The only independent, somewhat dynamical variable is $θ$, which suggests that $θ=$time.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I mean its position $\vec{r}$ changes in response to a change in angle $\theta$. Don't we then have to say either 1) expressions like "move", "reach", etc. need not imply the passage of time, or 2) any change in any variable implies the passage of time?

Comment: Yes, "change" implies the passage of some kind of time, even if it is the numbers of the pages in a flip book. With the answers given and the comment discussion you should now have a clearer idea of what your question is in fact about. Please edit and update the question to reflect that, so that then this discussion thread can be pruned of irrelevant or then redundant comments.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I'm afraid it'll take me some time to digest the responses enough to improve the question. If you'd like to edit it, please feel free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This definition of $\vec{e}_r,\,\vec{e}_\theta$ in terms of $\vec{e}_i:=\vec{i},\,\vec{e}_j:=\vec{j}$ has the elegant consequence$$\vec{e}_k\cdot\vec{e}_l=\delta_{kl}$$whether we stick to the Cartesian or polar coordinate system, as well as$$\frac{d}{d\theta}\vec{e}_r=\vec{e}_\theta,\,\frac{d}{d\theta}\vec{e}_\theta=-\vec{e}_r.$$Thus$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}(f(r,\,\theta)\vec{e}_r+g(r,\,\theta)\vec{e}_\theta)=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}-g\right)\vec{e}_r+\left(f+\frac{\partial g}{\partial\theta}\right)\vec{e}_\theta.$$If $\vec{e}_\theta$ weren't a unit vector, we'd have various coefficients complicating these display-line results, which would be especially confusing for orbits where $r$ varies. As it is, the position vector $\vec{r}=r\vec{e}_r$ satisfies $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\vec{r}=r\vec{e}_\theta$ (not to mention $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\vec{r}=\vec{e}_r$), which is orthogonal to $\vec{r}$ because $\vec{r}\cdot\vec{r}$ is $\theta$-independent. (If you're interested in why, for example, a physicist might find all this interesting, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_central-force_problem#Qualitative_properties).) Meanwhile, the equations$$\vec{i}=\cos\theta\vec{e}_r-\sin\theta\vec{e}_\theta,\,\vec{j}=\sin\theta\vec{e}_r+\cos\theta\vec{e}_\theta$$help us prove$$\nabla r=\frac{1}{2r}\nabla\vec{r}\cdot\vec{r}=\vec{e}_r,\,\nabla\theta=\cos^2\theta\nabla\frac{y}{x}=\frac1r\vec{e}_\theta,$$a system of vectors orthonormal to $\partial_r\vec{r},\,\partial_\theta\vec{r}$ in the sense discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvilinear_coordinates#Covariant_and_contravariant_bases).

Comment: I'm a fair way off understanding that, but it might be a useful map, so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Circumferential and radial components vectors are differently sized. There is a fixed ratio between them.

If the logarithmic spiral angle is $\alpha $ then

$$\dfrac { r(\theta)\, d\theta } {d\,r(\theta)}=\tan \alpha = m $$

(here wlog $ \dfrac{d\theta}{dt}=\omega = 1 $ )

Integrate
$$ r= r_i e^ {m\theta }$$

If $m$ is small we have a slow progressing spiral, *never* asymptotic to starting $r= r_i.$

Comment: Yes, equal to tan of spiral angle $\alpha$

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "Circumferential and radial components vectors are differently sized", given that $\vec{e_r}$ and $\vec{e_\theta}$ are both defined to have unit length?

Comment: But vector differentials are not of the same length,he  ratio of their magnitudes is not $1$.

Comment: Don't we have $\vec{e_r}:=\vec{i}\cos\theta+\vec{j}\sin\theta$ with $|\vec{e_r}|=\sqrt{\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta}=1$ and $\vec{e_\theta}:=\frac{d}{d\theta}(\vec{e_r})=-\vec{i}\sin\theta+\vec{j}\cos\theta$ with $|\vec{e_\theta}|=\sqrt{(-\cos\theta)^2+\sin^2\theta}=\sqrt{\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta}=1$?

Comment: I am assuming that you want to define a general spiral where the tangent makes an angle to radius that is not necessarily $ 45^{\circ}$